# Implications of SEO for single page websites

Tags: seo, javascript, cloaking

I built a server application that handles bot requests for my website, which was built using AngularJS. It works great, but I'm not entirely sure if it's valid in terms of Google's policy for SEO.

In short, the server hits the API that powers the site and generates a static html, which it then serves to any bots that access the site.

The static html file or 'snapshot' displays the same information as it's sibling page which is rendered on the browser, but I'd like to just display a slightly modified version for the bots to read.

Is this considered a violation of Google's SEO policy?

EDIT: I've already seen this : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7549306/single-page-js-websites-and-seo?rq=1 but the top answerer indicates that he is not sure of the implications that may occur if you adopt this model.

Comment: LGTM. Have you read [this wonderful tutorial](http://www.yearofmoo.com/2012/11/angularjs-and-seo.html) by one of the author of AngularJS?

Comment: @Blackhole I didn't read that particular article, but it is generally the same information that is all over the internet on this subject, so nothing new. The major hassle with this is that I'd rather not mix some SEO junk into my Angular app, and would like to deal with it separately on the server. It's just a design choice of mine.

Answer (score 1):

Showing modified versions to search engines is called [cloaking](https://support.google.com/webmasters/answer/66355?hl=en).  Google will penalize sites that do that, whether the site is a single page website or not.    Static html snapshots are fine as long as:

- Users and Googlebot see the same content
- Googlebot can crawl the content
- Users can land from search results "deep" in the site and see the specific content that they searched for.